# How to map one to many relationship in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

We have a scenario to give the input for a single header - multiple lines. In that case we don't know to map the values using excel in web driver. Please provide us the solution. Refer below Test Data.

For Header

`PurchaseNumber, PurchaseDate, SupplierName, SupplierSite`

`1, 10-Mar-2014, XXX, YYY`

For Lines

`ItemName, Quantity, Price`

`ABC,10, 15`

`BCD, 20, 20`

`DEF, 14, 13`

Comment: Hi user3401000, and welcome to Stack Overflow! There's not really enough information here to be able to provide a satisfactory answer to your question. Do you have any HTML that can be provided? What has been tried so far that proved unsuccessful? What language are you using?

Comment: The language we are using is Java

Comment: Okay. What about the other two questions, can you clarify further on those?